# Как сделать продолжение консольного приложения

Tags: c++

Я сделал консольное приложение, и мне надо чтобы по окончании программы можно было продолжить работу с ним, то есть запустить еще раз функцию main и все что в ней находится, не выходя из консоли?

Comment: Бесконечный цикл?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, можно всю `main` вынести в другую функцию, а ее уж запускать из `main` - переименуем `main` в `domain` и напишем что-то вроде

```
int domain(int argc, const char * argv[]) { ... }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(;;) // Ну, или ваши условия
        domain(argc,argv);
}
```

Второй вариант - функции семейства [`exec...`](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/spr/084.php) - типа

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (i == 9) system("pause");
    else
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        char parm[10];
        sprintf(parm,"%d",i+1);
        execl(argv[0],argv[0],parm,0);
    }
}
```